# Django rest-framework : Unit tests are using the production database

Tags: django, unit-testing, django-rest-framework

I'm currently working on a small app to learn about Django and Django-Rest-Framework and stumbled across a small issue related to unit testing.

I just have two applications in my project : api (which provides a RESTful api to mess around with the DB), and web (which just sends queries to the api and applies a layout to render web pages). Nothing complicated.
However, when launching unit tests, those testing the api work as expected and seem to use the temporary DB, but those testing the web application seem to use the production database.

Here is my model (api.models) :

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    country = models.CharField(max_length=32, verbose_name="Country of origin", name="country", blank=True, null=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=32, verbose_name="Phone", name="phone", blank=True, null=True)
    field = models.CharField(max_length=32, verbose_name="Field of occupation", name="field", blank=True, null=True)
    occupation = models.CharField(max_length=32, verbose_name="Occupation", name="occupation", blank=True, null=True)
    birthdate = models.DateField(verbose_name="Birth Date", name="birthdate", auto_now_add=False, auto_now=False, blank=True, null=True)
    description = models.TextField(verbose_name="Description", name="description", blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

Here is is the web view which causes problems (web.views):

```
def profile(request, usrname):
    """Handles profile page behaviour and rendering"""
    stdlogger.info("PROFILE : request for home page")

    if request.method == "GET":
        # retrieve single profile
        stdlogger.debug("PROFILE_get : request for profile of '" + usrname + "' retrieval")
        r = get("http://localhost:8000" + reverse("get_delete_update_profile", kwargs={'usrname': usrname}))
        if r.status_code == status.HTTP_200_OK:
            form = UserForm(data=r.json())

            if not form.is_valid():
                # login data is invalid
                stdlogger.error("PROFILE_get : form data is invalid")
                for field, errors in form.errors.items():
                    for error in errors:
                        stdlogger.error(field + " -> " + error)
                        messages.add_message(request, messages.ERROR, field + " : " + error)

            return render(request, 'web/profile.html', {'form': form, 'usrname': usrname, })
        else:
            stdlogger.error("PROFILE_get : profile for '" + usrname + "' could not be found")
            return HttpResponseNotFound()
```

And here is a unit test which causes problems (web.tests.test_views) :

```
from django.test import TestCase, Client

class getProfileTest(TestCase):
"""Test module for GET requests on Profile page"""

    def setUp(self):
        self.client = Client(enforce_csrf_checks=False)
        self.john = get_user_model().objects.create(
        username='john', password='test', first_name='John', last_name='Doe', country='UK', email='test@test.com',
        phone='+44123456789', field='Diplomacy', occupation='Spy', birthdate='1963-05-01', description='Tall guy')

    def test_valid_get_profile(self):
        response = self.client.get(reverse('profile', kwargs={'usrname': self.john.username}))
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
        self.assertTemplateUsed(response, 'web/profile.html')
```

This test returns a Http code 404 and when I run a logger through it, it shows production users, not 'John Doe'

Would anyone have any idea? :)

Comment: I'm not sure about your problem, but even so, if you are not familiar with them, I highly suggest you to look into : Dependency Injection Pattern, Dependency Inversion Principle and Inversion of Control containers. It will help you write less redundant code between production and tests, make clearer code and individualize your parts (non dependent).

Comment: I didn't know there was a dependency injection mechanism in Django (even if it was to be expected ;) )
Would you have any example of issue in my code and how it could be avoided?

Comment: Hmm, lets see, I'd say your problem could be `r = get("http://localhost:8000" + reverse("get_delete_update_profile", kwargs={'usrname': usrname}))` you don't seem to change `http://localhost:8000` by case, so you're always hitting on the same DB, no ?

Comment: Yes I am
(I also plan on replacing the hard-coded part of the url once I figurate out how it is done :) )